Omnetpp "no such modele type" error while creating a simple network
I am very new at using Omnetpp. By using the Simulaton Manual of Omnetpp, when I write the code blow to create a simple network, each nodes give "Node: no such module type" error. I know it seems there should be a mechanism to install and import modules, but unfortunately I don't know how. Could anyone please help me?
{
    submodules:
        node1: Node;
        node2: Node;
        node3: Node;
        node4: Node;
    connections:
        node1.port++ <--> {datarate=100Mbps;} <--> node2.port++;
        node2.port++ <--> {datarate=100Mbps;} <--> node4.port++;
        node4.port++ <--> {datarate=100Mbps;} <--> node6.port++;
       
} 

Thank you for your time.
Best regards.

in your folder there should be a Node.ned and a corresponding node.cc,  and in node.cc should include a line Define_Module(Node) after using namespace omnetpp
you may check it.
